# What's new LabVIEW NXG?

Tags: labview

What would be the advantage of using the new LabVIEW NXG, This new software seems to be simpler and intuitive, not having many codes, just blocks of signal acquisition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ZOOM!  What more do you need?

NXG is a complete rewrite of the LabVIEW IDE.  It is supposed to be simpler, more open, and integrate more functionality into the IDE instead of relying on other applications like Measurement and Automation Explorer (MAX).  It still has a long way to meet feature parity of what I call "classic LabVIEW".  But NI was unable to even consider some features they really want to do without this overhaul (30 year old code that nobody wants to touch).  With each new release, you will be seeing more and more of the code features we are used to (like NXG 2.0 is scheduled to have Object Oriented Programming).

Comment: Sigh... as LabVIEW old-timers everywhere know, if you think you need zoom then your block diagram is too big. ;-)

Comment: I was being sarcastic with that first line.  It was the most requested feature.  But I am with you, you are doing too much in your VI if you find you need to zoom out.  I am willing to consent that some people need the zoom in in order to wire properly.